# Equality comparison result unused in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, ios9.3

I just moved to iOS 9 and noticed some new warnings on my old code:

description.becomeFirstResponder == YES;

Display warning 'Equality comparison result unused'

How can I handle this Warning.

Thank You!

Comment: Fix your code.  The warning is telling you precisely what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you Avi@ How can I handle in code?can you please explain once.

Comment: what is description ?

Comment: If you want to assign value then you should use `=` instead of `==`. `==` is used to compare. for example if you want to use in `if statement` then use `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to assign, as in:

```
description.becomeFirstResponder = YES;
                                 ^
```

(`==` is the equality comparison operator).

The compiler is complaining as the result of the comparison wasn't being used, as it would be in:

```
if (description.becomeFirstResponder == YES) { /* do something */ }
```